# How to change data directory for Docker Rootless?

Tags: docker, rootless

The only info about rootless data dir on the official Docker Docs website is:

**The data dir is set to ~/.local/share/docker by default. The data dir should not be on NFS.**

However I didn't found any option to change this during installation via ***dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install***

Change default data directory for Docker on non-root user (rootless mode).

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default this in the config file. The config file is under `~/.config/docker/daemon.json`. This is how to customise data directory:

```json
{
  "data-root": "/your/folder"
}
```

You can find more info in docker doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#daemon-data-directory) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).

Comment: I don't have `~/.config/docker/daemon.json` file

Comment: Yes, it's usually not there. Just create it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had to restart the Docker service after creating `~/.config/docker/daemon.json`